# Выключение ПК в Windows

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Дорогие, помогите.

Такая задача: необходимо программно выключить ПК, только не так давно сел за C++
в С билдере я знаю, как выключить, а вот на Visual Studio 2008 - не могу.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если в билдере Вы выключаете без помощи компонент, то перевести это на Visual Studio в большинстве случаев - сtrl+c = crtlv+v.

Comment: Вот

ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN, NULL);

В билдере робит, а на VS не хочет, это я так понимаю функция самого билдера.

Comment: так ведь проще :)

    system("shut down -s -t 10");

Comment: Для функции system надо что то подключать? а то не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Visual C++ выключение будет выполнятся с использованием той же функции Windows API, как и Builder C++, а именно: [ExitWindowsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28VS.85%29.aspx).